# Issue - cloning remote repo 'origin;

Tags: github, jenkins

All of a sudden I started getting below error, when trying to run Automation scripts through Jenkins.

Jenkins setup was very stability very stable and scripts were running fine.
I am trying to understand what went wrong , what could be the root cause and how to fix it. Appreciate your help.

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' 
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch...." returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr:ERROR: Repository not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I was going through different threads for this error, but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Check first what URL your Jenkins job is using, and if it is an SSH or HTTPS one.

That way, you can check if the SSH key (for an SSH URL) or the credentials (for HTTPS) are incorrect or not.

For instance, a remote GitHub repository would no longer accept a password, or a [token with the old format](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/).